Adding sector titles to a chordDiagram
I've made a chord diagram from the overlap of two datasets. I've managed to add a main title above the chord.
However, I also want to add a title for each of the two datasets. Perhaps text that wraps around the outside of the chord adjacent each half that is relevant to each dataset. Or maybe another ring outside the first which has a solid bar round the bottom half for dataset1's title, and another at the top for dataset2's title.
Below is an example. Any help would be much appreciated!
comparison_table <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 19, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 184, 0, 
0, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 
0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 
0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
51, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
179, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 
0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(15L, 24L), dimnames = structure(list(c("black1", 
"blue1", "brown1", "cyan1", "green1", "greenyellow1", "grey601", 
"lightgreen1", "magenta1", "pink1", "purple1", "red1", "tan1", 
"turquoise1", "yellow1"), c("black2", "blue2", "brown2", "cyan2", 
"darkgreen2", "darkgrey2", "darkorange2", "darkred2", "green2", 
"greenyellow2", "grey2", "grey602", "lightcyan2", "lightgreen2", 
"lightyellow2", "magenta2", "orange2", "pink2", "purple2", "red2", 
"royalblue2", "salmon2", "tan2", "white2")), names = c("", ""
)), class = "table")

colour_vector <- c(black1 = "black", blue1 = "blue", brown1 = "brown", cyan1 = "cyan", 
green1 = "green", greenyellow1 = "greenyellow", grey601 = "grey60", 
lightgreen1 = "lightgreen", magenta1 = "magenta", pink1 = "pink", 
purple1 = "purple", red1 = "red", tan1 = "tan", turquoise1 = "turquoise", 
yellow1 = "yellow", black2 = "black", blue2 = "blue", brown2 = "brown", 
cyan2 = "cyan", darkgreen2 = "darkgreen", darkgrey2 = "darkgrey", 
darkorange2 = "darkorange", darkred2 = "darkred", green2 = "green", 
greenyellow2 = "greenyellow", grey2 = "grey", grey602 = "grey60", 
lightcyan2 = "lightcyan", lightgreen2 = "lightgreen", lightyellow2 = "lightyellow", 
magenta2 = "magenta", orange2 = "orange", pink2 = "pink", purple2 = "purple", 
red2 = "red", royalblue2 = "royalblue", salmon2 = "salmon", tan2 = "tan", 
white2 = "white")

chord_title <- "My comparisons"

# Clear existing circos plot to reset parameters
circos.clear()

# Set gap degrees for sectors
circos.par(gap.after = c(rep(1, length(rownames(comparison_table)) - 1), 10, rep(1, length(colnames(comparison_table)) - 1), 10),
           canvas.xlim = c(-1.2, 1.2), # Adjust x-axis limits for more space
           canvas.ylim = c(-1.2, 1.2)) # Adjust y-axis limits for more space

# Create chord diagram
chordDiagram(comparison_table, 
             transparency = 0.5, 
             grid.col = colour_vector,
             annotationTrack = "grid",
             preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = 0.2))

# Add custom tracks and annotations
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, ylim[1] + cm_h(2),sector.name,
              facing = "clockwise",niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5))
  circos.axis(h = "bottom",labels.cex = .6,sector.index = sector.name)
}, bg.border = NA)

# Add the title
title(chord_title)


Reviewing posts on stack and also documentation on chorDiagrams. Can't find a solution.
